# Issues with Presto and Mongodb

Tags: mongodb, presto

I have prestoDB installed and am trying to connect to Mongodb and I see the following issue when I try to query the Mongodb:

```
presto:admin> db.collection.count();
Error running command: java.io.IOException: unexpected end of stream on Connection{hostname:27017, proxy=DIRECT hostAddress=/hostname:27017 cipherSuite=none protocol=http/1.1}
```

Here are my config properties:

```
[root@ushdbld00058lb openplatform]# cat /opt/presto-server-0.181/etc/catalog/mongodb.properties
connector.name=mongodb
#mongodb.seeds=host1,host:port
mongodb.seeds=hostname:27017
mongodb.schema-collection=test
mongodb.credentials=XXXXXXXXX:XXXXXXXXXXX@admin
#mongodb.min-connections-per-host=
#mongodb.connections-per-host=
#mongodb.max-wait-time=
#mongodb.connection-timeout=
#mongodb.socket-timeout=
#mongodb.ssl.enabled=
#mongodb.read-preference=
#mongodb.write-concern=
#mongodb.required-replica-set=
#mongodb.cursor-batch-size=`
```

Comment: Just to clarify, 1) what is your MongoDB version? 2) is the reachable host of your `mongod` is really `hostname` or is just to obscure while posting ? 3) Can you connect using [mongo shell](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/mongo/) ? if so could you post a command to connect with it (some sensitive information redacted) ? This would show if you require `SSL` option etc.